# Centering one image on the corner of another image

Tags: android, design-patterns

How can I take a center of an image and put in on a corner of another image?

[image]

Comment: Use Photoshop or Gimp. If you want a better answer than that please add some context to your question. While the problem might seem super clear to you, the question you asked leaves much room for interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ConstraintLayout` to get this behavior, for example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewCenter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/drawable1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewToPosition"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/imageViewCenter"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageViewCenter"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageViewCenter"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageViewCenter"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/drawable2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

if you have issues with constraint layouts, consider trying the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/#0)